# How to remove null value from data separated by comma

Tags: jquery

I have some problems getting a value from my dynamic textboxes. My textboxes look like this:

[image]

This is my HTML code to get values:

```
$('#pilihtambahan input[type=text]').each(function(index) {
    if (valData2 == "") {
        valData2 = valData2 + $(this).val();    
    } else {
        valData2 = valData2 + "," + $(this).val();  
    }
});
```

If I insert a value in textbox "jumlah sewa showcase" with "1" and insert text in "jumlah sewa stove" textbox with "2" the result will be like this

```
1,<null>,2
```

I have no idea to remove the `null` value. My goal is the result will be like this

```
1,2
```

Maybe someone can help me to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: use `.length` to see if its null or not

Comment: hey @AminGharavi Thank you for your answer, can u give me an example, i am new with jquery things. Thank You

Comment: @Rei do not use .length because null.length will throw error. You have to do like this suppose `a` is your value then check `if(a.toString().trim()=="null" ||a.toString().trim()==""){ //it comes here}`. it will do your job

Comment: @Santhucool given that the elements have to exist to be selected by jQuery the `length` property will *never* be null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the `length` property of the value before you append it to the string.

However a better method would be to build an array of the values using `map()` then `join()` them together. As an empty string value is falsy you can use a ternary expression within `map()` to return the required value or skip it entirely. Try this:

```
var values = $('#pilihtambahan input[type=text]').map(function(index) {
    return this.value ? this.value : null;
}).get().join(',');
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcutdn96/)

Answer (score 1):

Check with `$(this).val().length` or `$(this).val()!=""`

Your modified code would be:

```
$('#pilihtambahan input[type=text]').each(function(index) {
      var val = $(this).val();
      if (val.length) {
        if (valData2 == "") {
          valData2 += valData2 + val;
        } else {
          valData2 = valData2 + "," + val;
        }
      }
});
```

OR

```
$('#pilihtambahan input[type=text]').each(function(index) {
      var val = $(this).val();
      if (val !="" && val!=null) {
        if (valData2 == "") {
          valData2 = valData2 + val;
        } else {
          valData2 = valData2 + "," + val;
        }
      }
});
```

To enhance more you could do:

```
$('#pilihtambahan input[type=text]').each(function(index) {
      var val = $(this).val();
      if (val.length) {
        if (valData2 == "") {
          valData2 += val;
        } else {
          valData2 += "," + val;
        }
      }
});
```

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding,, :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  arr = [];
  $('input[type=text]').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    //if(value){
    if (value.length) {
      arr.push(value);
    }
  });

  console.log(arr);
  $('p').html(arr)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<br />
<input type="text">
<br />
<input type="text">
<br />
<button class="btn">
  test
</button>
<p>

</p>
```